# Trouble with replacing bytes in binary files

Tags: c#

There are two programs involved.  The first one has a string like "@@@@@@@@@@". The second one is a config tool to find "@@@@@@@@@@"  and replace this string with user input from a textbox.

Now I have trouble in the replacing part. Here is the code.

```
    //This is code from first program:
    string myIP = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
    string myPort = "%%%%%%%%";
    int port = Int32.Parse(myIP );
    tcpClient.Connect(myIP , port);

    //This is code from second program：
    //Get bytes from textbox: 
    byte[] byte_IP = new byte[60];
    byte_IP = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1_ip.Text);
    //Get all bytes in the first program:
    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"before.exe");
    //Replace string with textbox input, 0x1c00 is where the "@" starts:  
    Buffer.BlockCopy( byte_IP, 0, buffer, 0x1c00, byte_IP.Length);
    //Build a new exe:
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"after.exe", buffer);
```

However, I get "127.0.0.1@.@.@.@.@.@." in the new exe. But I need "1.2.7...0...0...1........." to process as a valid host.

Comment: Can you share your entire code for both methods (program1 and program2) because there is nothing in the code you posted that replaces any character

Comment: Wait... So, are you modifying an executable by replacing some bytes? Is there some reason for choosing this particular way of doing things? ([Hint, there are better ways.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Besides the fact that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to really understand the problem, your question is unclear in other ways. E.g. what are all the periods in your examples strings in the description after your code example?

Comment: Also, why are you even doing this? It's barely reliable to patch strings in binaries if you are replacing an exact number of characters, but to try to patch an variable-length string like an IP address? Doable, but the code will be a lot more complicated than you probably guess. If you must patch a binary (and you really shouldn't) better to store the IP address itself as binary, and surround it with some kind of binary markers so you can search the binary data and make sure you're replacing the right data. But really, you should use the registry, or a manifest or config file for this purpose.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Because the second program is like a configuration tool with windows forms that somebody else ( they don't know any code) uses to setup ip and so on in the first program. Well, this is the only method I know.

Comment: @theB Yes, I want to edit an executable by replace some bytes. First, this is the only way I know. Second, I need to write a configuration tool for people who can't program to setup their own executable with different ip address and port and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to reiterate what has already been said in the comments: there are simpler ways to handle this stuff.  That's what config files are for, or registry settings.

But if you absolutely must...

First, you have to match the encoding that the framework expects.  Is the string stored as UTF8?  UTF16?  ASCII?  Writing data in the wrong encoding will turn it into pure garbage, almost every time.  Generally for strings in code like you're looking for you'll be wanting to use `Encoding.UNICODE`.

Next, you need some way to deal with strings of different lengths.  The buffer you define needs to be large enough to contain the widest string you want to be able to set - 15 bytes for dotted numeric IPv4 addresses - but you have to allow for the minimum of 7 characters.  Padding the remainder and removing that padding before using the value will probably suffice.

The minimum program I could think to use for testing this was:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var addr = "@@@.@@@.@@@.@@@".TrimEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Address: [{0}]", addr);
    }
}
```

Now in your patcher you will need to locate the starting position in the file and overwrite the bytes with the new string's bytes.  Here's a Patch method, which calls a `FindString` method that you will have to write yourself:

```
static void PatchFile(string filename, string searchString, string replaceString)
{
    // Open the file
    using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        // Locate the search string in the file (needs to be implemented)
        long pos = FindString(file, searchString);
        if (pos < 0)
            return;

        // Pad and limit replacement string, then convert to bytes
        string rep = string.Format("{0,-" + searchString.Length + "}", replaceString).Substring(0, searchString.Length);
        byte[] replaceBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rep);

        // Overwrite the located bytes with the replacement
        file.Position = pos;
        file.Write(replaceBytes, 0, replaceBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Can you recommend a tutorial for config files? I've no idea how config files work. My clients don't know programming at all. They either edit a txt or need a windows application ( what i'm trying to do) to configure address and port and so on.

Comment: If it's just to let them make changes to their own settings I'd use the registry.  Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx